# How to transfer NiFi flowfiles from one queue to another?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have "unmatched" flowfiles in a queue. Is there any way to transfer these flowfiles into another queue?

[image]

**EDIT:**

> WITH @Andy's SUGGESTED SOLUTION - #RESOLVED

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bryan's answer is comprehensive and explains the ideal process for on-going success. If this is a one-time task (*I have this queue that contains data I was using during testing; now I want it to go to this other processor*), you can simply select the queue containing the data and drag the blue endpoint to the other component.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to directly transfer between queues because it would take away the meaning of how those flow files got in the queue. They have to pass through the previous processor which is making the decision about which queue to place them in. You can create loops using a processor that does nothing like UpdateAttribute, and then connect that back to the original processor.